# Can a Kusto table have multiple update policy?

Tags: bigdata, azure-data-explorer, kql, data-mapping

I have a Kusto table and want to ingest data from two azure blob locations. Data from both sources need some transformation, hence I defined two update policies. So now I have two source tables and one destination table. The first update policy was working fine, and then I went on defining the second update policy which also worked fine. But after that when I observe, data was not getting ingested from the first source(It is present in the temporary source table) to the target table. I wonder if defining the second update policy somehow disabled the first update policy? Is it possible to have two update policies on one destination table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to have two update policies on one destination table?

Yes, it is possible.

You may want to verify that you have an array of 2 update policies defined on the target table, and that you didn't overwrite the first with the second using the `.alter` policy command.

Comment: Oh yes, I used alter table for the second policy creation. Got it, we just specify the array of update policies in one .alter command. Thank you so much. You literally saved me.

Comment: It's the same control command, just make sure you include both objects in the serialized array (between the square brackets) and not just one. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/update-policy